# Array/List iteration without extra object allocations

Tags: kotlin

I'm working on a game written in Kotlin and was looking into improving GC churn. One of the major sources of churn are for-loops called in the main game/rendering loops that result in the allocation of iterators.

Turning to the documentation, I found this paragraph:

> A for loop over an array is compiled to an index-based loop that does not create an iterator object.
>
> If you want to iterate through an array or a list with an index, you can do it this way:

```
for (i in array.indices)
  print(array[i])
```

> Note that this “iteration through a range” is compiled down to optimal implementation with no extra objects created.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops

Is this really true? To verify, I took this simple Kotlin program and inspected the generated byte code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val arr = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
    for (i in arr.indices) {
        println(arr[i])
    }
}
```

According to the quote above, this should not result in any objects allocated, but get compiled down to a good old pre-Java-5 style for-loop. However, what I got was this:

```
      41: aload_1
      42: checkcast     #23                 // class "[Ljava/lang/Object;"
      45: invokestatic  #31                 // Method kotlin/collections/ArraysKt.getIndices:([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lkotlin/ranges/IntRange;
      48: dup
      49: invokevirtual #37                 // Method kotlin/ranges/IntRange.getFirst:()I
      52: istore_2
      53: invokevirtual #40                 // Method kotlin/ranges/IntRange.getLast:()I
      56: istore_3
      57: iload_2
      58: iload_3
      59: if_icmpgt     93
```

This looks to me as if a method called `getIndices` is called that allocates a temporary `IntRange` object to back up bounds checking in this loop. How is this an "optimal implementation" with "no extra objects created", or am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**
So, after toying around a bit more and looking at the answers, the following appears to be true for Kotlin 1.0.2:

**Arrays:**

- `for (i in array.indices)`: range allocation
- `for (i in 0..array.size)`: no allocation
- `for (el in array)`: no allocation
- `array.forEach`: no allocation

**Collections:**

- `for (i in coll.indices)` range allocation
- `for (i in 0..coll.size)`: no allocation
- `for (el in coll)`: iterator allocation
- `coll.forEach`: iterator allocation

Comment: Related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5075

Comment: [KT-12611](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12611) states that `indices` optimization was included in Kotlin 1.0.3.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I know the only allocation-less way to define a `for` loop is

```
for (i in 0..count - 1)
```

All other forms lead to either a `Range` allocation or an `Iterator` allocation. Unfortunately, you cannot even define an effective reverse `for` loop.

Comment: True, this gets rid of the `IntRange` allocation. Which is interesting, because it's still denoting an IntRange syntax wise. Thanks! Worth filing a bug against the documentation for this? It's misleading at best.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: clearly compiler magic at work, since as soon you pull out `0..count - 1` into a function acting on the array, it results in an `IntRange` allocation.

Comment: That's a pure compiler optimization and I suppose there will be more in future. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11173

Comment: After investigating Ilya's answer more, I don't think this should be the accepted answer anymore. Any of the 3 suggestions result in no extra allocations, given the iterable is an array, NOT a list.

Answer (score 52):

To iterate an array without allocating extra objects you can use one of the following ways.

1. `for`-loop

```
    for (e in arr) {
        println(e)
    }
```

2. `forEach` extension

```
    arr.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
```

3. `forEachIndexed` extension, if you need to know index of each element

```
    arr.forEachIndexed { index, e ->
        println("$e at $index")
    }
```

Comment: Now this is interesting. I assumed all of these would lead to the allocation of iterators--but they don't, at least not if the iterated object is an array. They do for Lists and other collection types. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of preparing a list and iterate with index and value.

```
val list = arrayListOf("1", "11", "111")
for ((index, value) in list.withIndex()) {
   println("$index: $value")
}
```

Output:

0:1

1:11

2:111

Also, following code works similar,

```
val simplearray = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
for ((index, value) in simplearray.withIndex()) {
    println("$index: $value")
}
```